# Delphi Datasnap RESTful API method works in browser but not with POST in python

Tags: python, rest, http, delphi, datasnap

I'm new to web development and especially REST stuff. 
I'm trying to get user data from the following link which is a REST service built with Datasnap in Delphi:
http://XXXXXX:XXX/datasnap/rest/Tdm/LoginUser

I do not have access to the back-end of that service (or any of its code), however I'm still required to figure out how to work with it.

You can actually use it in the browser like so:
http://XXXXX:XXX/datasnap/rest/Tdm/LoginUser/ANY_STRING/EMAIL@EMAIL.COM/PASSWORD

And it works perfectly, prints a JSON response with all user data in it.

Now, I'm trying to do the same, but this time with a POST request via the request library in Python. Here's the part of the code in question:

```
import requests
import json

task = {
    'FAppKey':'test', 
    'Email':'REDACTED :)', 
    'Password':'12345' 
    }
header = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
    'Connection': 'keep-alive', 
    'Accept': 'text/html', 
    'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'
    }

response = requests.post('http://XXXXX:XXXX/datasnap/rest/Tdm/LoginUser/', 
    json=json.dumps(task), 
    headers=header)
print(response, response.text)
```

As you can see, I'm trying to send a POST request containing JSON object with the data of the specific user that I want to see. This however, does not work. The print statement returns the following:

> {"error":"Tdm.updateLoginUser method not found in the
>   server method list"}

Which is strange, because there is indeed no such method called "updateLoginUser" in the API.

I am assured that datasnap and LoginUser method in particular are configured correctly and the problems I'm experiencing are from my side.

What am I doing wrong and how do I POST correctly to a REST API? Why would Datasnap print an error that references another method that does not exist?

**EDIT:**
Fixed it!

Couple of things:

- When you use POST, DataSnap automagically appends "update" to the method name (so "Foo" becomes "updateFoo"), expecting you to have a method there. If you don't, you have to put the method name in quotation marks, which of course in URL encoding is "%22"
- When you're passing multiple parameters in JSON over POST, you have to put every parameter in a list/array, and then put that list in a dict with the key "_parameters" like so:

```
task = { "_parameters" : ["param1", "param2", "param3"] }
```

Documentation for all of this can be found [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/DataSnap_REST_Messaging_Protocol).

Comment: Does it work if you do `requests.post(f'http://76.169.101.20:6323/datasnap/rest/Tdm/LoginUser/{task['Email']}/{task['Password']} . . . )` instead?

Comment: Yes, it does. But I'm trying to accomplish the same with POST.

Comment: You are using `POST` here. Sometimes an endpoint is configured to receive arguments in the json `body` as you did earlier, sometimes it's configured to receive it as a path (as you did manually with `endpoint/email/password`). I think this endpoint may be only configured to receive arguments through a path.

Comment: That was my first instinct as well, but my assignment says that the service is configured for accepting arguments in POST requests as well :(

Comment: FWIW, "application/json" does not have a charset parameter.

Comment: @JulianReschke Didn't know that, thanks!